# Null Difference

Tags: .net

What is the difference between

```
if(null==object)
```

and

```
if(object==null)
```

Please give the advantage for using the above.

Answer (score 12):

The difference comes if you accidentally type `=` instead of `==`:

`if (null = object)` - Compiler error
`if (object = null)` - Bug!

Comment: In C# using assignment operator in place of boolean result is a compile time error.

Comment: that is good to know.. but the question wasn't originally marked 'C#' :D

Comment: Indeed... I've removed the tag

Comment: :) Agree. It is tagged in .net. Doesn't VB.Net or managed C++ provide this feature?

Comment: VB uses = for both assignment and equality.

Comment: VB uses = for value equality. When checking for nulls or reference equality, VB uses "Is".

Answer (score 6):

In the good old days, compilers would happily let you make assignments inside conditionals, leading to unintentional errors:

```
if(a = false)
{
  // I'll never execute
}
if(b = null)
{
  // I'll never execute 
}
b.Method(); // And now I'm null!
```

So some clever developers started putting their constants first in their conditionals:

```
if(false = a) // OOPS! Compiler error
{
  // ..
}
if(null = b) // OOPS! Compiler error
{
  // ..
}
```

So they trained themselves to avoid a whole class of errors.  Most modern compilers will no longer let you make that error, but the practice continues.

There is one other advantage to always putting your constants first:

```
if(myString != null && myString.Equals("OtherString"))
{
  // ...
}
```

can (in .NET, Java, and most languages with an object-based string type) be reduced to:

```
if("OtherString".Equals(myString))
{
  // ..
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, here is something I kind of like... use extensions:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNull(this object target)
    {
        return null == target;
    }
}
```

Now, you can forget about it completely:

```
if(item.IsNull())
```

Comment: I don't like that. I think is going a much too far with extensions. Also, I don't like calling static methods on member variables. And then it also requires a double take to see someone calling a method on a variable that presumably may be null. ... But it does work I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

No difference. (null == object) is a practice from C/C++, where "=" is both used as assignment operator, and as comparison operator.

There were too many errors when if (object = null) was used.

Comment: I have no connection with this post, but why someone just down voted it? I agree that it is duplicating the opinions but then instead of down voting person should just keep quite.

Comment: because the answer as originally submitted was neither complete nor helpful - "No difference" isn't enough :)

Comment: It's not a dup at all (the first 3 answers, including this one) appeared at the same time. And different explanations. Anyway, I just hate when something id downvoted w/o reason. I always put a comment when I downvote.

Comment: Get over it, Sunny. In the end you'll earn +8 pt, because someone (maybe me) will upvote your answer ;-)

Comment: "No difference" was more than enough for smart ones. What was the need to write Julius Caesar there?

Comment: splattne: it was not about me or about my answer. I post such a comments even on someone else's answers when they are downvoted w/o reason.

Comment: because he asked for "why" to use one over the other... so it wasn't a complete answer

Comment: warren: question in 2 parts - answer in 2 parts :). I read the second question later.

Comment: hehe - but it was only two lines!  =D

Comment: what to tell you, small buffer :)

Answer (score 2):

Some prefer `if (null == object)` so that if you accidentally type `=` instead of `==`, you get a compile error instead of an assignment.

Comment: ... if you're using C or C++, and haven't got warnings turned up high enough.

Answer (score 2):

*Logically*, there is no difference.

From an *error checking* point of view, the first is more desirable because if you miss an  equals sign (`=`), the compiler will let you know you can't make an assignment to a constant.

Answer (score 0):

In many languages == is the comparison operator = is the assignment operator.

It very easy to type = when you really mean ==.

Therefore the convention of typing constant==variable is preferred.

constant=variable will not compile thus showing you, your error.

variable=constant will compile and will do the wrong thing at runtime.