# Checking for null, which is better? "null ==" or "==null"

Tags: c#, .net, null

**Dupe: [Null Difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302701/null-difference)**

A lifetime ago I came across an article that explained that the following were not equal (in c#):

```
if (o == null) {}
if (null == o) {}
```

The article explained that the latter was preferred because it resulted in a more accurate test. I've been coding like that ever since. Now that I understand so much more I was looking for the article, or another like it, to see what the exact findings were, but I can't find anything on the subject.

Thoughts? Is there a difference? First glance would say no. But who knows what happens in the bowels of IL and C# compilation.

Comment: Duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302701/null-difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302701/null-difference)

Comment: Re: "But who knows what happens in the bowels of IL and C# compilation." -- Anyone with a copy of reflector?

Comment: ;) I thought that was for when one wanted see how they looked from the codes point of view...

I saw no diff, I even did performance tetsing with no diff. That's why I asked.

I prefer if (o==null)..it's more readable to me. Now, I can use it again. :)

Comment: checked with reflector, "ldnull, ldarg.1, ceq, ldc.i4.0, ceq" compared to "ldarg.1, ldnull, ceq, ldc.i4.0, ceq"

Comment: If the IL is equivalent, then why on earth would it matter?

Comment: That's why I asked - it didn't make sense. Perhaps I was missing something. Memories play a terrible trick on one and I thought there was some really good reasoning behind it - it was a c# exmaple after all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it's an old habit to prevent you from typing `if (o = null)`. if (null = o) is a syntax error. kind of pointless in C#, because null values aren't ever coerced into booleans.

Answer (score 3):

The latter is a holdover from the C/C++ days, where it was possible to accidentally assign a value instead of compare.  C# won't allow you to do this, so either/or is acceptable (but I find the former more readable).

Answer (score 2):

In c# there's no difference. It's an old habit from C/C++ developers to avoid a common bug where this is correct syntax:

```
if(o = null)
```

In C# that wouldn't compile but in C and C++ it would, leaving you with a pretty nasty bug. Therefore, many people got used to doing

```
if(null == o)
```

Answer (score 0):

Irrelevant for C#, this is from C. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399792/inadvertent-use-of-instead-of) for a discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I work with Java ..and I do have the habit of having constants on the LHS for all commutative comparisons.

```
"name".equals(name)

 null == obj

"55".compareTo(numString)
```

etc..Just avoiding unnecessary NullPointerExceptions...

Comment: For string literals (i.e. the first and third), that makes sense. For the middle one, it's an unnecessary readability penalty.