# Is there any difference between if(a==5) or if(5==a) in C#?

Tags: c#

Just I would like to know, is there any difference between

> if (a==5) or if (5==a)

in C#, Which one is better?

Comment: I believe this question is duplicated all over.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677264/operator-and-operands

Check this link

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no difference - assuming that "a" is an integer.

I know some people prefer `if (5==a)` because in c & c++ if you wrote `if (5=a)` by mistake you'd get a compiler error while `if (a=5)` would result in a bug.

C# raises a compiler error in the latter case, so it's not an issue.

Comment: It depends on what is "a". See my answer.
But generaly yes, you are right.

Comment: I was assuming that "a" was an integer of course!

Answer (score 9):

I'd actually say there is a difference, but it's not a technical one (as everyone has well covered already) - **readability**.  It matters and the first form is *much* more natural.

Answer (score 7):

The `if(5 == a)` construct is common in C/C++ because boolean values are represented using ints. Thus if you write `a = 5` by mistake this can be evaluated in the context of the `if`, which is most likely not what you wanted.

In C# there's no implicit conversion from `int` to `bool`, so if you type `=` instead of `==` you'll get a compile error.

Answer (score 5):

no difference, it is an old habit to avoid if(a=5) in c/c++.

These questions/answers are about the same:

- [(0 == variable) or (null == obj): An outdated practice in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655657/0-variable-or-null-obj-an-outdated-practice-in-c/655668#655668)
- [Checking for null, which is better? "null ==" or "==null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424842/checking-for-null-which-is-better-null-or-null/424852#424852)
- [Why does one often see "null != variable" instead of "variable != null" in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271561/why-does-one-often-see-null-variable-instead-of-variable-null-in-c/271575#271575)

Answer (score 3):

Both are equivalent. 
I remember when I used to code in C, I preferred 'if (5==a)' because it guarantees that I haven't typed 5=a accidentally as the compiler would throw error. This would not happen if we write  'if (a=5)'. Though it is a typo, it would not generate any compiler error and would go unnoticed.

But, in C# it is not the case. There is no logical reason to write 'if (5==a)'. If we had written 'if(a=5)', the compiler would throw an error. So in C# use 'if(a==5)'!

Answer (score 1):

With correct design, there is no difference between "a == 5" and "5 == a". But there is some special situation, where has "a == 5" and "5 == a" different behaviour. It's very unpropably, but it is posible.

Nevertheless this example is constructed for demonstration of the situation, and I **does not recomend** do thinks such this.

Example:

```
public class BadClass {
    public int Value;

    public static implicit operator int( BadClass c ) {
        return c.Value;
    }
    //public static implicit operator BadClass( int n ) {
    //    return new BadClass { Value = n };
    //}

    public static bool operator ==( BadClass c, int n ) {
        return (c.Value + 1 == n);
    }
    public static bool operator !=( BadClass c, int n ) {
        return (c.Value + 1 != n);
    }

    public override bool Equals( object obj ) {
        if ( obj is int ) {
            return (this == (int)obj);
        }
        else {
            return base.Equals( obj );
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
...
BadClass a = new BadClass { Value = 13 };
var rslt_1 = (13 == a); //there will be true
var rslt_2 = (a == 13); //there will be false
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than the safety `if (5==a)` gives you, No.

Comment: In C# there's no extra safety cause if (a=5) isn't allowed

Comment: @Brian: "if (a=5)" can be allowed, if "a" is some custom type which can be implicitly converted from int and implicitly converted to bool.

Comment: @TcKs: Correct but you don't see those very often do you? For bools you can make the assignment instead of comparison mistake if explicitly comparing with true, which is another good reason to avoid if (b == true).

Answer (score 0):

Only difference is if you forget the second equals, the first version is still a valid statement whereas the second version will raise a compile time error.

HTH

cheers,